# How to get emailBlurb from template via DocuSign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

If I load all templates via the docuSign api the property emailBlurb is always an empty string, emailSubject is available.

It is a spring boot 2 REST service.

```
public EnvelopeTemplateResults getAllTemplates() {
    // Check if valid token available
    loginService.checkToken();

    EnvelopeTemplateResults templateResult = new EnvelopeTemplateResults();
    TemplatesApi templatesApi = new TemplatesApi(com.docusign.esign.client.Configuration.getDefaultApiClient());
    List<EnvelopeTemplateResult> templateList;

    try {
        TemplatesApi.ListTemplatesOptions options = templatesApi.new ListTemplatesOptions();
        options.setInclude("notifications,recipients,custom_fields,folders");
        templateResult = templatesApi.listTemplates(configuration.getAccountId(), options);

        templateList = templateResult.getEnvelopeTemplates();

        templateResult.setEnvelopeTemplates(templateList);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        logger.error("Error in get all templates: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return templateResult;
}
```

Comment: above code does not show if you are reading emailBlurb or emailSubject, what are you trying to do? Are you trying to read emailBlurb and emailSubject of each of the template?

Answer (score 0):

Mike,

Please look in here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/templates for information about this.
You can make a GET call (`GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}`) to the template API and the top of the json you get back would look like this:

```
{
    "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Composite Templates",
    "emailBlurb": "Composite Templates Sample 1",
    "status": "sent",
```

(just cut the rest of the json)
where you can find what you need